# Specify attribute to return from Node JS function that generates a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Function getMyObject() returns a very long object called `responseObject`. I just want it to return a very specific attribute `mydata` which path is:

```
responseObject.data.GetNumber.GetId[1].a.dataset.mydata
```

How can I pass this "path" to `getMyObject()` so that it returns just `mydata`? The function should only return the attribute, the option to return the whole object then apply the "path" is not acceptable.

Comment: Is it possible to write a wrapper function that handles calling `getMyObject()` and applying the path for you?

Comment: @AJGregory no, getMyObject() should only return mydata